# Building Qt 5.6 for Windows Phone arm (error complaining about desktop)

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, qt5

I want to compile Qt 5.6 for Windows Phone (arm). If I configure, it complains about desktop platform. "Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported."

I just want the Windows Phone 8.1 version. Am I missing any configure option ?

```
C:\Qt\5.6\Src>configure -nomake examples -nomake tests -openssl-linked -I C:\include -L C:\lib\openssl\winphone\x86_arm -opensource -prefix C:\qt-5-6 -confirm-license -xplatform winphone-arm-msvc2013 -release

+ cd qtbase
+ C:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\configure.bat -top-level -nomake examples -nomake tests -openssl-linked -I C:\include -L C:\lib\openssl\winphone\x86_arm -opensource -prefix C:\qt-5-6 -confirm-license -xplatform winphone-arm-msvc2013 -release

This is the Qt for Windows Runtime Open Source Edition.

You have already accepted the terms of the license.

Creating qmake...

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl -c -Fo./ -Fdqmake.pdb  -W3 -nologo -O1  /MP /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS   -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\library -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\generators -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\generators\unix -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\generators\win32 -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\generators\mac -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\generators\integrity  -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\include -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\include\QtCore -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\include\QtCore\5.6.0 -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\include\QtCore\5.6.0\QtCore  -I..\src\corelib\global -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP  -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013   -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\tools\shared  -DQT_VERSION_STR=\"5.6.0\" -DQT_VERSION_MAJOR=5 -DQT_VERSION_MINOR=6 -DQT_VERSION_PATCH=0  -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DPROEVALUATOR_FULL  -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_COMPRESS  -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM  -DUNICODE -DQT_CRYPTOGRAPHICHASH_ONLY_SHA1 -DQT_JSON_READONLY -DQT_NO_STANDARDPATHS -c -Yc -Fpqmake_pch.pch -TP C:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\qmake_pch.h
qmake_pch.h
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\x86_ARM\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        del qbitarray.obj  qbuffer.obj  qcryptographichash.obj  qfilesystementry.obj  qfilesystemengine.obj  qfilesystemengine_win.obj  qfilesystemiterator_win.obj  qfsfileengine.obj  qfsfileengine_iterator.obj  qarraydata.obj  qbytearray.obj  qvsnprintf.obj  qbytearraymatcher.obj  qdatetime.obj  qdir.obj  qdiriterator.obj  qfiledevice.obj  qfile.obj  qtemporaryfile.obj  qabstractfileengine.obj  qfsfileengine_win.obj  qsystemlibrary.obj  qfileinfo.obj  qglobal.obj  qhash.obj  qiodevice.obj  qringbuffer.obj  qdebug.obj  qlist.obj  qlinkedlist.obj  qlocale.obj  qlocale_tools.obj  qlocale_win.obj  qmalloc.obj  qmap.obj  qregexp.obj  qtextcodec.obj  qutfcodec.obj  qstring.obj  qstring_compat.obj  qstringlist.obj  qstringbuilder.obj  qsystemerror.obj  qtextstream.obj  qdatastream.obj  quuid.obj  qvector.obj  qsettings.obj  qlibraryinfo.obj  qvariant.obj  qsettings_win.obj  qmetatype.obj  qxmlstream.obj  qxmlutils.obj  qnumeric.obj  qlogging.obj  qjson.obj  qjsondocument.obj  qjsonparser.obj  qjsonarray.obj  qjsonobject.obj  qjsonvalue.obj
C:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\qbitarray.obj konnte nicht gefunden werden
        del project.obj main.obj ioutils.obj proitems.obj qmakevfs.obj  qmakeglobals.obj qmakeparser.obj qmakeevaluator.obj qmakebuiltins.obj  makefile.obj unixmake.obj unixmake2.obj mingw_make.obj  option.obj winmakefile.obj projectgenerator.obj property.obj meta.obj  makefiledeps.obj metamakefile.obj xmloutput.obj  msvc_nmake.obj msvc_vcproj.obj msvc_vcxproj.obj  msvc_objectmodel.obj msbuild_objectmodel.obj registry.obj  cesdkhandler.obj
C:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\project.obj konnte nicht gefunden werden
        del qmake_pch.obj
C:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\qmake_pch.obj konnte nicht gefunden werden
        del qmake_pch.pch
C:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\qmake_pch.pch konnte nicht gefunden werden
        del qmake.pdb
C:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\qmake.pdb konnte nicht gefunden werden
        del qmake.ilk
C:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\qmake.ilk konnte nicht gefunden werden
        del qmake.tds
C:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\qmake.tds konnte nicht gefunden werden

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl -c -Fo./ -Fdqmake.pdb  -W3 -nologo -O1  /MP /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS   -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\library -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\generators -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\generators\unix -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\generators\win32 -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\generators\mac -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\generators\integrity  -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\include -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\include\QtCore -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\include\QtCore\5.6.0 -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\include\QtCore\5.6.0\QtCore  -I..\src\corelib\global -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP  -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013   -IC:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\tools\shared  -DQT_VERSION_STR=\"5.6.0\" -DQT_VERSION_MAJOR=5 -DQT_VERSION_MINOR=6 -DQT_VERSION_PATCH=0  -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DPROEVALUATOR_FULL  -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_COMPRESS  -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM  -DUNICODE -DQT_CRYPTOGRAPHICHASH_ONLY_SHA1 -DQT_JSON_READONLY -DQT_NO_STANDARDPATHS -c -Yc -Fpqmake_pch.pch -TP C:\Qt\5.6\Src\qtbase\qmake\qmake_pch.h
qmake_pch.h
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\x86_ARM\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
Building qmake failed, return code 2
```